# There is a foreign-key-syntax-error

Tags: java, sql, foreign-keys, syntax-error, android-sqlite

I'm getting an error with this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE trip (
   tid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   from_trip TEXT,
   to_trip TEXT,
   seat_cost INTEGER,
   pickup TEXT,
   date INTEGER,
   time INTEGER,
   tmid INTEGER,
   FOREIGN KEY (tmid) REFERENCES member(KEY_MID),
   tcid INTEGER,
   FOREIGN KEY (tcid) REFERENCES carinfo(KEY_CID)),
   seats INTEGER
);
```

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.user.apple, PID: 3547
>                     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "tcid": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE trip(tid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,from_trip TEXT,to_trip TEXT,seat_cost INTEGER,pickup TEXT,date INTEGER,time INTEGER,tmid  INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (tmid) REFERENCES member(KEY_MID) ,tcid INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (tcid) REFERENCES carinfo(KEY_CID) ),seats INTEGER ) ;

Comment: You have an extra closing bracket after the ... `REFERENCES carinfo(KEY_CID)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//this in datahelper class
//using cursor to getid from another table

```
   public Cursor getId(String tableName)
    {

    String query = ("insert into trip tmid select mid from member");
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return  c;
     }
//this in my main activity
//calling cursor
            public void onClick(View v) {
            long isInserted = myDb.createride(etfrom.getText().toString(),
                    etto.getText().toString(),
                    etdate.getText().toString(),
                    ettime.getText().toString(),
                    etpick.getText().toString(),
                    etcost.getText().toString(),
                    etseat.getText().toString());
            if (isInserted > 0){

                Cursor cursor = myDb.getId(myDb.TABLE_MEMBER);
                startManagingCursor(cursor);

                while(cursor.move(0)) {
                    int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                }
     //this is how i using to get value to table
        public long createride(String from_trip,String to_trip,String date,String time,String pickup,String cost,String seats) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_FROM,from_trip);
    values.put(KEY_TO,to_trip);
    values.put(KEY_DATE,date);
    values.put(KEY_TIME,time);
    values.put(KEY_PICKUP,pickup);
    values.put(KEY_SEATS,seats);
    values.put(KEY_SEAT_COST,cost);

    long insertId = db.insert(TABLE_TRIP, null, values);

    return insertId;
}
```

Comment: this is getting value from parent table but adding to preceding rows

Answer (score 0):

Don't interleave FK constraints with column constraints; either use the in-line version:

```
mycolumn int references othertable
```

*or* explicit constraints after *all* columns:

```
mycol1 int,
mycol2 int,
foreign key (mycol1) references othertable,
foreign ket (mycol2) references othertable2 (somecol)
```

It is optional to mention the column of the referenced table if the referenced column is the primary key (which you should define anyway).

So, change:

```
CREATE TABLE trip (
   tid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   ...
   tmid INTEGER,
   FOREIGN KEY (tmid) REFERENCES member(KEY_MID),
   tcid INTEGER,
   FOREIGN KEY (tcid) REFERENCES carinfo(KEY_CID)),
   seats INTEGER
);
```

which has another syntax error with mismatched brackets, to:

```
CREATE TABLE trip (
   tid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   ...
   tmid INTEGER REFERENCES member,
   tcid INTEGER REFERENCES carinfo,
   seats INTEGER
);
```

Comment: foreign key value is null or not refrencing the value from parent table.please help

Comment: @thinker what do you mean? Is that an error message? Do you want to insert nulls in FK columns? Sounds like a different question, not related to this question, so you should probably post a new question.

Comment: in my above trip table the two foreign key  should get the value from my two parent table.the two parent table as values but foreign key value is empty or null.What should i do to get the value??

Comment: or i have to write **query** even though i have referenced

Comment: you can either insert a null then update it after if you know how to link it back, or insert it at the time, eg `insert into trip (..., tmid, tcid, ...) values (..., (select KEY_MID from member where <whatever>), (select KEY_CID from carinfo where <whatever>), ...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
    public long createride(String from_trip,String to_trip,String date,String time,String pickup,String cost,String seats) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_FROM,from_trip);
    values.put(KEY_TO,to_trip);
    values.put(KEY_DATE,date);
    values.put(KEY_TIME,time);
    values.put(KEY_PICKUP,pickup);
    values.put(KEY_SEATS,seats);
    values.put(KEY_SEAT_COST,cost);
    long insertId = db.insert(TABLE_TRIP, null, values);

    return insertId;
}
```

Comment: please help with what are the changes required for the above to get primary key of other table.